# ASP.NET (4.X - NOT Core) - How to Set up Azure AD Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory

Does anyone have experience setting up Azure AD on an ASP.NET 4.X website?  I've registered my app in Azure and have been trying to follow the instructions here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

However, the following docs regarding SSO, etc. are written for ASP.NET MVC/Core applications.

I've tried using OWIN, and it kinda looks like it's working.  I get a login prompt, enter my credentials, and pass through, but I had configured IIS 7 to use Windows Auth, so it might be picking up on that. (I've read that Azure authentication is done at the application level, not IIS, so my previous IIS settings might not be affecting anything.)

Does anyone have advice?  I don't have experience adding authentication to a website and appreciate any help.  Ideally, I was told I'd hit my organizations 365 login page, authenticate through it, and pass on to my website, but this isn't happening.  I just get a standard popup login box.  (It works, but I don't know if I'm authenticating through Azure.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio 2019 [Create a new ASP.NET (not Core) Web Application wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-aspnet-core?view=vs-2019#create-a-project). Choose any option that supports Authentication and set it to Cloud - Single or Multiple Organizations:

[image]